# Using innerHTML in a directive with template string

Tags: angular

I have a directive that changes the text of a button when it's loading state is set. I want it to work when the innerHTML is a template string. Any ideas?

For example:

`<button [buttonLoader]="loading" buttonLoaderText="Loading...">Hello {{plant}}</button>`

At the moment only `Hello` is shown.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input } from '@angular/core'

@Directive({
  selector: '[buttonLoader]'
})

export class ButtonLoaderDirective {

  @Input('buttonLoader') loading
  @Input('buttonLoaderText') loadingText: string

  origEl: string

  constructor (private _el: ElementRef) {
  }

  ngOnInit () {

    this.origEl = this._el.nativeElement.innerHTML

    this.loading && this.loading
      .subscribe((value) => {
        let changeTo = (value ? this.loadingText || 'Loading...' : this.origEl)
        this._el.nativeElement.innerHTML = changeTo
      })

  }

}
```

Comment: Implementation will be depended on input values. In your case what is the input value type of "loading" variable? Observable?

Comment: I create a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qmkkoh). This will show you how normal text input works. If the Input value is an Observable then the implementation change slightly.